# linear fit on log log axis plot does not fit the data

Tags: c, curve-fitting, least-squares

When I try to fit a linear curve to my data points the curve does not match my data. The line is below my data points and the slope is too deep, too. It could be due to starting at x=10 and its corresponding y value, but I am not sure. least square method should be correct, as I tried multiple ways of calculating slope and intercept, but all look methods produce the same output.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PATH_GNUPLOT "your/path/gnuplot"

void ERROR(char* error_string);

int main() {

    // first 10 data points are irrelevant
    double data[100] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0.242910, 0.235523, 0.228976, 0.223114, 0.217820, 0.213005, 0.208597, 0.204539, 0.200786, 0.197299, 0.194047, 0.191003, 0.188146, 0.185456, 0.182916, 0.180513, 0.178234, 0.176068, 0.174006, 0.172039, 0.170160, 0.168362, 0.166639, 0.164987, 0.163399, 0.161872, 0.160402, 0.158984, 0.157617, 0.156297, 0.155020, 0.153785, 0.152590, 0.151431, 0.150308, 0.149218, 0.148159, 0.147131, 0.146131, 0.145158, 0.144211, 0.143289, 0.142391, 0.141515, 0.140661, 0.139827, 0.139014, 0.138219, 0.137442, 0.136683, 0.135941, 0.135215, 0.134504, 0.133809, 0.133128, 0.132461, 0.131807, 0.131166, 0.130538, 0.129922, 0.129318, 0.128725, 0.128142, 0.127571, 0.127010, 0.126458, 0.125916, 0.125384, 0.124861, 0.124346, 0.123840, 0.123342, 0.122853, 0.122371, 0.121897, 0.121430, 0.120970, 0.120518, 0.120072, 0.119633, 0.119200, 0.118774, 0.118354, 0.117939, 0.117531, 0.117128, 0.116731, 0.116340, 0.115953, 0.115572};

    int n = 100;

    /* calc fit */
    double sumx, sumy, sumx2, sumxy, a, b = 0.0;

    // => log(y) = a * log(x) + b
    // data starts at 10 for x value
    for (int i = 10; i < n; i++) {

        double x = log(i);
        double y = log(data[i]);

        sumx += x;
        sumx2 += x * x;
        sumy += y;
        sumxy += y * x;
    }

    a = (n * sumxy  -  sumx * sumy) / (n * sumx2 - sumx*sumx);
    b = (sumy * sumx2  -  sumx * sumxy) / (n * sumx2 - sumx*sumx);
    /* end calc fit */

    

    /* save data and plot */
    FILE *fp = fopen("data.dat", "w");
    
    if (fp == NULL) {
        ERROR("failed to open data.dat");
    }
    
    for (int i = 10; i < n; i++)
        fprintf(fp, "%d %.16lf\n", i, data[i]);
    
    fclose(fp);

    FILE *GNUpipe = popen(PATH_GNUPLOT, "w");
    
    if (GNUpipe == NULL) {
        ERROR("failed to open gnuplot");
    }
    
    fprintf(GNUpipe, "set term png\n");
    fprintf(GNUpipe, "set logscale xy\n");

    // log(y) = a * log(x) + b
    // => y = x**a + 10**b              
    fprintf(GNUpipe, "Fit(x) = x**%lf * 10**%lf\n", a, b);
    
    fprintf(GNUpipe, "plot [0.1:%d*1.1] 'data.dat' title 'error', ", n);

    fprintf(GNUpipe, "Fit(x) title 'fit'\n");
    
    pclose(GNUpipe);

}

void ERROR(char* error_string) {
    
    fprintf(stderr, error_string);
    
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

[image]

EDIT:

Code so far with all changes implemented:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PATH_GNUPLOT "your/path/gnuplot"

void ERROR(char* error_string);

int main() {

    // first 10 data points are irrelevant
    double data[100] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0.242910, 0.235523, 0.228976, 0.223114, 0.217820, 0.213005, 0.208597, 0.204539, 0.200786, 0.197299, 0.194047, 0.191003, 0.188146, 0.185456, 0.182916, 0.180513, 0.178234, 0.176068, 0.174006, 0.172039, 0.170160, 0.168362, 0.166639, 0.164987, 0.163399, 0.161872, 0.160402, 0.158984, 0.157617, 0.156297, 0.155020, 0.153785, 0.152590, 0.151431, 0.150308, 0.149218, 0.148159, 0.147131, 0.146131, 0.145158, 0.144211, 0.143289, 0.142391, 0.141515, 0.140661, 0.139827, 0.139014, 0.138219, 0.137442, 0.136683, 0.135941, 0.135215, 0.134504, 0.133809, 0.133128, 0.132461, 0.131807, 0.131166, 0.130538, 0.129922, 0.129318, 0.128725, 0.128142, 0.127571, 0.127010, 0.126458, 0.125916, 0.125384, 0.124861, 0.124346, 0.123840, 0.123342, 0.122853, 0.122371, 0.121897, 0.121430, 0.120970, 0.120518, 0.120072, 0.119633, 0.119200, 0.118774, 0.118354, 0.117939, 0.117531, 0.117128, 0.116731, 0.116340, 0.115953, 0.115572};

    int n = 100;

    /* calc fit */
    double sumx = 0.0; 
    double sumy = 0.0; 
    double sumx2 = 0.0;
    double sumxy = 0.0;
    double a = 0.0;
    double b = 0.0;

    // => log(y) = a * log(x) + b
    // data starts at 10 for x value
    for (int i = 10; i < n; i++) {

        double x = log(i);
        double y = log(data[i]);

        sumx += x;
        sumx2 += x * x;
        sumy += y;
        sumxy += y * x;
    }

    int N = n - 10;
    double denom = N*sumx2 - sumx * sumx;
    b = (sumy * sumx2 - sumx * sumxy)/ denom;
    a = (N*sumxy - sumx * sumy)/ denom;

    printf("%g %g\n",a , b);
    /* end calc fit */

    

    /* save data and plot */
    FILE *fp = fopen("data.dat", "w");
    
    if (fp == NULL) {
        ERROR("failed to open data.dat");
    }
    
    for (int i = 10; i < n; i++)
        fprintf(fp, "%d %.16le\n", i, data[i]);
    
    fclose(fp);

    FILE *GNUpipe = popen(PATH_GNUPLOT, "w");
    
    if (GNUpipe == NULL) {
        ERROR("failed to open gnuplot");
    }
    
    fprintf(GNUpipe, "set term png\n");
    fprintf(GNUpipe, "set logscale xy\n");

    // log(y) = a * log(x) + b
    // => y = x**a * 10**b              
    fprintf(GNUpipe, "Fit(x) = x**%.16lf * 10**%.16lf\n", a, b);
    
    fprintf(GNUpipe, "plot [0.1:%d*1.1] 'data.dat' title 'error', ", n);

    fprintf(GNUpipe, "Fit(x) title 'fit'\n");
    
    pclose(GNUpipe);

}

void ERROR(char* error_string) {
    
    fprintf(stderr, error_string);
    
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

"data.dat": [link](https://pastebin.com/dY699gjN)
stdout: `-0.323977 -0.66909` for `printf("%g %g\n",a , b);`

Comment: `double sumx, sumy, sumx2, sumxy, a, b = 0.0;` only initialises `b` to `0.0`. All the other variables in that line are uninitialised and probably contain random junk.

Comment: Fixed it (thanks) but that didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @Max, Code comment `// => y = x**a + 10**b` looks amiss.  Should it be `// => y = x**a * 10**b`?

Comment: Yes, fixed the comment. Was correct in the fprintf statement, tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least these problems:

**Need to zero initialize**

```
// double sumx, sumy, sumx2, sumxy, a, b = 0.0; 
double sumx = 0.0;
double sumy = 0.0;
...
```

**Save time**

Enable more warnings: "warning: excess elements in array initializer"

**Too many initializers**

```
// double data[100] = {  101 initializers };
```

**Avoid losing precision**

```
// fprintf(GNUpipe, "Fit(x) = x**%lf * 10**%.*le\n", a, b);
fprintf(GNUpipe, "Fit(x) = x**%.16le * 10**%.16le\n", a, b);

// fprintf(fp, "%d %.16lf\n", i, data[i]);
fprintf(fp, "%d %.16le\n", i, data[i]);
```

**Wrong `n`**

Code uses `n`.  Since, `for (int i = 10; i < n; i++)`, should be `n-10` in `a, b` formulas.

***Maybe* wrong formula?**

Looks wrong to me, need deeper review.

```
// ??
a = (n * sumxy  -  sumx * sumy) / (n * sumx2 - sumx*sumx);
b = (sumy * sumx2  -  sumx * sumxy) / (n * sumx2 - sumx*sumx);
```

I expect: [ref](https://byjus.com/maths/linear-regression/).

```
N = n - 10;
double denom = N*sumx2 - sumx * sumx;
a = (sumy * sumx2 - sumx * sumxy)/ denom;
b = (N*sumxy - sumx * sumy)/ denom;
```

Ah, I see we have `a, b` reversed.

---

[Append]

**Wrong base**

Code is using `log()` (log base-e).  Likely wants `log10()` if `"Fit(x) = x**%lf * 10**%lf\n"` is important.

Comment: Sorry, maybe copied one date too much. Data (array) and data.dat (file) should look something like this https://pastebin.com/dY699gjN. Deleted the last date in the array.

Comment: @max To be clear, the real mistake is not enabling all warnings, not so much _too many initializers_.

Comment: When compiling like `gcc .\stackoverflow_minExample.c -std=gnu99 -lm`, I am not getting any warnings. How do I enable them?

Comment: @Max `-Wall` should be the flag.

Comment: Try "-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion".

Comment: Add `-Wshadow` and then `-Werror` (to keep yourself honest `:)` (in addition to what @chux-ReinstateMonica said) Confused by all the options? Perfect time to learn. See [man 1 gcc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica x starts at value 10. So the first data point is `(10, data[10])`

Comment: and what I am supposed to do with that ref link?

Comment: I used the code from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083465/fast-efficient-least-squares-fit-algorithm-in-c

Comment: Ummmm ... look up what each of the options do for you to start with `:)` That way you learn what options are available to compile your code. When you begin using an IDE -- you can tell the IDE how you want your code compiled -- instead of hoping the IDE set the options you need and enabled all warnings for you (they don't)

Comment: @Max "x starts at value 10. So the first data point is (10, data[10])" --> do not use `n` in `a = ..., b = ...`, use `(n-10)`.

Comment: The line appears to be parallel now, but the intercept is still off https://imgur.com/a/Xw841GL

Comment: @Max 1) Note minor change to `fprintf(fp, "%d %.16le\n", i, data[i]);`.  2) Try `printf("%g %g\n",a , b);`.  What do you get?

Comment: `a: -0.323978,  b: -0.669088` returns your statement in my code

Comment: I get `-0.323977 -0.66909`.  I do not see our difference as significant to your plot, yet curious.  Perhaps it is time to _append_ your current solution to the question.  Also post  `stdout` and `"data.dat"`.

Comment: @Max Do you want `log()` or `log10()`?

Comment: Updated answer.  I think I do want `log10()`. Gnuplot sets logscale with log10, right? So this "linear" correlation should be in log10?

Comment: yes, `log10()`with all your previous effort has fixed it.